# Baby and Infant tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Baby is synonymous with infant. Often, when people say baby (other than as a term of endearment), they are typically referencing an infant. I find that infant is a bit more descriptive than baby. Can we make "baby" a tag synonym of infant?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, make [baby](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby) a synonym of [infant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant).**

My initial thought was to agree with Karl.  However, upon looking at [baby](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby), I see it has only been used 21 times.  Every one of those would seem to do better with one of our age-specific tags ([newborn](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newborn), [infant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant), or [toddler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toddler)).

I believe making [baby](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby) a synonym of one of the age specific tags.  I'm not certain which tag makes the most sense, though.  I'm inclined towards agreeing that [infant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant) makes most sense, so I consider a vote for this answer to be a vote for making [baby](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby) a synonym of [infant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant).

However, since there are other synonym possibilities, I'll post separate answers.  If you feel one of the other choices is a better synonym, **don't vote for this answer; vote instead for the other**.

Regardless of which synonym we choose, this would require some cleanup, first.

In some cases, [baby](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby) replaces one of our age-specific tags, in which case the question isn't tagged appropriately (e.g. the question is about an 18 month old, and it is tagged [baby](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby), so someone searching the tag [toddler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toddler) won't be able to find it).

In other cases, it is present in conjunction with an age-appropriate tag.

In a few cases, it relates to a baby that has not yet arrived: [Querying a database for baby names within popularity range?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8408/querying-a-database-for-baby-names-within-popularity-range) and [Adopt before giving birth or give birth before adopting?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/adopt-before-giving-birth-or-give-birth-before-adopting).

**Cleanup Suggestions**

In any case where [baby](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby) is used with an existing age-specific tag, it should simply be removed.

In any case where it is used instead of an age-specific tag, it should be replaced with the appropriate age-specific tag.

In the two examples for a child who has not yet arrived (the database on baby names, and the adoption vs. birth questions), I think the tag should be removed altogether.

Comment: Have you added votes for infant and I just can't find it?

Comment: @ChristopherW This one is for "infant".  The others are for "toddler" and "newborn".

Comment: Oh wow. Sorry. I should stop coming to meta late at night.

Comment: No worries... I do use a dozen different tags in this one answer, so it doesn't stand out nearly the way the others do.  Poor formatting choice on my part, in retrospect.

Comment: Can we declare this vote closed? :)

Comment: @Joe I'm not comfortable saying it is a clear consensus when there are only 2 votes between this answer and a conflicting answer.  This is why we need more meta participation :(

Answer (score 1):

I think "baby" is a broader term.  Most people I know use the term "baby" up until around age two or three, whereas "infant" refers specifically to a baby who is younger than around a year, before they learn to walk, which is when they become a "toddler".

Comment: What would the implementation for this be, then?  "Baby" should be included in all questions also tagged "newborn", "infant" and "toddler"?

Answer (score 0):

Vote for this if you agree [with my synonym reasoning and cleanup suggestions](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/656/420), but feel that [newborn](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newborn) makes more sense as a synonym, instead of [infant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant).

Answer (score 0):

Vote for this if you agree [with my synonym reasoning and cleanup suggestions](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/656/420), but feel that [toddler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toddler) makes more sense as a synonym, instead of [infant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant).